# Getting System.Type from TypeSymbol in roslyn analyzer

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, analyzer

I want to create a diagnostic analyzer to check if a class can be instantiated. I have my class declaration and I'm trying to use Activator.CreateInstance(parameter) but this needs System.Type as its parameter. Is it possible to achieve this in Roslyn?

ClassDeclarationSyntax classSyntax = context.Node as ClassDeclarationSyntax;
INamedTypeSymbol type = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(classSyntax) as INamedTypeSymbol;
Activator.CreateInstance(?);

Comment: What would you expect it to do if the type symbol refers to a type in the code being compiled? That compiled code isn't actually loaded, so there isn't a type to instantiate...

Comment: I basically want to check if the class can be instantiated (it should have a default constructor in case a parameterized constructor is present). I know I can check this via constructorDeclarationSyntax but wanted to know if just instantiating a class in Roslyn is feasible as via the former approach I'm missing some cases due to some internal factors.

Comment: Instantiating the type means the type has to be present as a CLR type... and if this is a type you're compiling (or a type in a dependency that isn't loaded in the code using Roslyn), that just won't be the case.

Comment: A _non-static_ class can always be instantiated: via Reflection from everywhere the type is available at runtime, and from source where both the type and the constructor are accessible. What are you trying to achieve? Either determine if a type has the implicit default constructor or an explicit parameterless constructor? Or determine if you could create a new instance of that type in source, for which the location of the `new` operation is critical, deciding if that type + constructor is accessible or inaccessible. Mind `public`, `private` and `internal`, with or without `InternalsVisibleTo`.